# How to get a specific hash value from a specific string?

Tags: javascript, hash, cryptography, lightning

I am looking at some docs for Lightning invoices creation at https://github.com/lightning/bolts/blob/master/11-payment-encoding.md#now-send-24-for-an-entire-list-of-things-hashed.

They say a SHA256 hash of

```
One piece of chocolate cake, one icecream cone, one pickle, one slice of swiss cheese, one slice of salami, one lollypop, one piece of cherry pie, one sausage, one cupcake, and one slice of watermelon
```

is

```
8yjmdan79s6qqdhdzgynm4zwqd5d7xmw5fk98klysy043l2ahrqs
```

When I create an invoice with a LND, it returns an invoice which is when decoded, shows the same value, but when I try to hash the source string with JavaScript or with online tools, I never get a string like that.

Here is what I get with JavaScript:

```
createHash('sha256').update(str).digest('hex')

3925b6f67e2c340036ed12093dd44e0368df1b6ea26c53dbe4811f58fd5db8c1
```

Online tools gives no the result I expect as well.

So, I suppose there is some extra encode/decode procedure happening under the hood.

How do I turn `One piece of chocolate cake, one icecream cone, one pickle, one slice of swiss cheese, one slice of salami, one lollypop, one piece of cherry pie, one sausage, one cupcake, and one slice of watermelon` into `8yjmdan79s6qqdhdzgynm4zwqd5d7xmw5fk98klysy043l2ahrqs`?

Comment: The link you provided mentions something called 'bech32' encoding. The string `8yjm..` appears to be some kind of 32-character encoding, so I'd guess that's the ticket. It would be encoding the 32 bytes of the digest, not the hex version of the digest. But I'm not motivated to look up bech32 encoding.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I think bech32 is used to encode whole invoice, not parts of it so I am afraid it doesn't give a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the [`bech32-converting`](https://github.com/hojttaler/bech32-converting) lib to check this:

```
conv = require('bech32-converting')
conv("").toBech32("3925b6f67e2c340036ed12093dd44e0368df1b6ea26c53dbe4811f58fd5db8c1")

> '18yjmdan79s6qqdhdzgynm4zwqd5d7xmw5fk98klysy043l2ahrqspe7lh6'
```

which contains the result... Note there is a `1` is prepended and `pe7lh6` :

The first char (`1`) is the [Bech32 separator](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0173#Bech32) which is always `1` (using `conv("bc")` above would prepend `bc` for example)

The last six characters (`pe7lh6`) are the [Bech32 checksum](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0173#Checksum)

Comment: This indeed helps! A lot of documentation is missing on how to build around lightning but your answer is just to the point!